# UiCollectionView individual cell design

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Continuing with my UICollectionView learning experience I am stuck on one last issue.

My UIcollection got 5 sections with 8 cells each. I use the selectCellForIndexPath to use the cells to load levels, and with the help of some community member I solved 1 of my issues already.

The problem I have now is that certain cells are supposed to be locked until you have unlocked the previous level. I am using bool values to keep track of the unlocked levels.

So what I am trying to do now is show a second image with a lock on all the cells/levels that are not unlocked yet. 
I am using a custom cell that has a label and 2 image views, one being the lock. In the method cellForItemInIndexPath I am using these bool value to check if a cell is unlocked and therefore hide the lock image. The code looks something like this

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier.cell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCel

// level label    
cell.levelLabel.text = self.cells[indexPath.row]

// main cell image
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.cellImages[indexPath.section])

// check unlock image 
if indexPath.section == 0 {
        switch indexPath.row {
           case 0:
           if level1Unlocked {
              cell.lockImage.hidden = true
           }
           case 1:
           if level2Unlocked {
              cell.lockImage.hidden = true
           }
           ...
    }
}
if indexPath.section == 1 {
      switch....
     ....
}
```

My custom cell looks like this

```
import SpriteKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

// MARK: - Properties

/// Background
var imageView: UIImageView!
var lockImageView: UIImageView!

/// Header
var levelLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: - Init
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    /// Image
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    #if os(tvOS)
    imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
    #endif
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    /// Lock Image View
    lockImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    lockImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Lock")
    lockImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    lockImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    #if os(tvOS)
        lockImageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
    #endif
    contentView.addSubview(lockImageView)

    /// Level label
    levelLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    levelLabel.font = UIFont(name: Label.Font.noteworthy, size: 22)
    levelLabel.textColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    //textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    levelLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    levelLabel.center.y = 0 + 30
    contentView.addSubview(levelLabel)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}
```

The main issues are the following

1) some cells dont show the lock (I check the above code a few times to make sure its correct)

2) as soon as I start scrolling and than come back to a cell it shows/doesnt show the lock image although its supposed to.

3) I played around with removing/adding the lock image instead of hiding, but the result is the same.

I think it has something to do with reusable cells. Could somebody please help and put me in the right direction of how I can manage individual cell appearance that persist until you reload the collection view data.
I am doing this programatically as I am overlaying the collection view on a SKScene, so please no storyboard tips.
Thank you very much

Comment: Could you show us your CustomCollectionViewCel.m ?

Comment: Just updated the answer with my custom cell. I have just being playing around with using 2 custom cells and than returning the correct cell depending on the bool values. It works. However I still would prefer to just use 1 custom cell to avoid duplicate code. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this some more it seems the only solution that worked reliably for me is using 2 custom cells instead of 1 cell and trying to hide certain labels.
In my selectCellForItemAtIndexPath method I now do this.

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier.cell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

 let cellLocked = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier.cellLocked, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCellLocked
```

Than I simply return the correct cell depending on the level unlock states.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is typical for recycled cells. The cells are "dequeued", so unless you re-configure them, they can show old data or state.

Solution: Make sure you make a full configuration of **all** cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, including setting the `lockImage.hidden` to `true` or `false` explicitly as necessary.

For example, instead of only setting to true with an if statement

```
cell.lockImage.hidden = level1Unlocked
```

This will *hide* it if `level1Unocked` is true, and *show* it if not.

BTW, your setup with dedicated variables for each level seems also to be suboptimal design, but perhaps that is another question.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing tho with a custom cell and checking the bool values in cellForItemAtIndexPath? Thanks by the way

Comment: It seems you are not doing it.

Comment: Could you please check my updated answer of how my code in cellForItemAtIndex looks. I didnt post the customCell code since it essential only contains the  1 label and 2 image views. Any idea why that would cause issues?

Comment: Please see my expanded answer explaining the difference between what I stated and what you were doing.

Comment: Hey, I just checked your answer. Wow that is actually a trick I did not know in regards to just settings something hidden directly = the bool value. I am still fairly new to coding so thank you very much for that, super helpful. I have actually asked a question here in regards to keeping track of level progress. I am curious how a game like AngryBirds 2 keeps track of 200+ levels. I have been playing around with property lists etc. What do you suggest for that? You dont have to post a detail answer but just letting me know what to read about would be nice.  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
// Lazy load your views in your CustomCell.m
lazy var imageView: UIImageView  = {
    var temporaryImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    temporaryImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    temporaryImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    #if os(tvOS)
    temporaryImage.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
    #endif
    return temporaryImage
}()


// Remove all the custom stuff that we added to our subclassed cell
func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    imageView = nil
}
```

Then remove the imageView initialization from init.

Repeat for the 2 other components you have.
I learnt a long time ago it's  the best way to create customCells without the help of the storyboard.

NB : I'm not used to Swift, so forgive me if I made a mistake

Comment: hey thank you I will check this out also. Ill report back tomorrow. Thanks a bunch